# Reflection on Servlet, Httpservletrequest type is getting RequestFacade type and cannot invoke method

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, reflection

Im trying to invoke a method using reflection, the method parameter is HttpServletRequest type but the parameter in execution get RequestFacade and cannot invoke the method, here is my code

Servlet code:

```
 /**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //processRequest(request, response);
    String test = (String)request.getParameter("testingText");
    String methodToCall = (String)request.getParameter("method");
    Method method;
    try {
        method = this.getClass().getMethod(methodToCall, HttpServletRequest.class, HttpServletResponse.class);
        method.invoke((HttpServletRequest)request, (HttpServletResponse)response);
        //test(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException{
    processRequest(request, response, "test");
}

public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException{
    processRequest(request, response, "handleRequest");
}
```

And here is the JSP

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="Controller">
        <input type="hidden" name="method" value="test"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Testing text" name="testingText" />
        <input type="submit" value="Click me!" />
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="Controller">
        <input type="hidden" name="method" value="handleRequest"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Testing text" name="testingText" />
        <input type="submit" value="Click me!" />
    </form>
</body>
```

The `doPost` is getting called, and the method is found, but in the invoke fails because of different types.
If I try using `method = this.getClass().getMethod(methodToCall, request.class, response.class);` the method cant be found.

I tried creating new variables of `HttpServletRequest` type, but the variables remain the type `RequestFacade` and if i cast the parameters in the call of the method the method is not invoked, because the parameters remain the same type.

I found that the parameters got the type `RequestFacade`from the package `org.apache.catalina..`
And finally I cannot change the method parameter types because I cannot use that package.

PD: I just used the type `RequestFacade`and `HttpServletRequest` in the post for simplicity but I understand that there is a `ResponseFacade` and `HttpServletResponse` types.

Comment: What exception do you get, specifically?

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class` this is the Exception that I get when im debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `Method#invoke()` method incorrectly

```
method.invoke((HttpServletRequest)request, (HttpServletResponse)response);
```

[See the javadoc for that method here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

The first argument must be an instance on which to execute the method. The 2nd+ arguments are optional, ie. varargs, which are the arguments to the method. Use it like so

```
method.invoke(this, (HttpServletRequest)request, (HttpServletResponse)response);
```

where `this` references your `Servlet` instance. If the method was in some other class, you would need an instance of that class.